# how to revert a commit that caused a merge in the gitk tree?

Tags: git, merge

one of my team mates made a commit and pushed it. It caused a merge in the git tree.
problem is that the code is tagged and this push makes it look like the commit is before the tag. Actual case is that the commit is after the tag.
There are other pushes after this merge. Now, I want to completely remove this commit from the gitk tree. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no way to change the look of the gitk tree without rewriting the history and then pushing it with `git push -f ...`. If you want to revert the merge commit itself (the changes, that was merged into your branch) you can use `git revert <commit-hash>` as you would do with a normal commit. It would create a new commit reverting the changes from the merge commit.

The easy way to remove the merge commit from the tree is

- `git checkout -b TESTING` (Create a temporary branch to test with)
- `git branch TMP <commit-on-YOUR-branch-just-before-merge>`
- `git rebase TMP -i`

You will have to remove in the editor all commits from the other branch that was merged into your branch. If everything does well:

- `git branch -f YOUR_BRANCH TESTING`
- `git push -f ...`

Comment: I was hoping I could do a git reset HEAD or something similar and get rid of the commit from the tree

Comment: With `git reset ...` you can remove last commits, but then you have to push your change with `git push -f` and that will cause troubles for other team members. Also your tag will stay unless you move it and put it with `git push --tags -f`.